# React useState hooks error: Argument of type 'xxx' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<xx>'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, tsx

I use react hooks to update, but notice error when setState.

> Argument of type '{ alertRules: any; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction'.
>     Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'alertRules' does not exist in type 'SetStateAction'.ts(2345)

Here is my code.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { FieldArray } from 'redux-form';
import { CoordinateSelect } from '~/fields';
import lodash from 'lodash';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { filterDispatchers } from '~/actions';
import t from '~/locale';

interface Props {
  getAlertRules(o: object): Promise<any>;
}
type Alert = {
  ...
}

const connector = connect(
  null,
  filterDispatchers('getAlertRules'),
);

const AlertRuleForm = (props: Props) => {
  const [alertRules, setAlertRules] = useState<Alert[]>([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  const fetchData = async () => {
    const actionResult = await props.getAlertRules({ limit: -1 });
    const alertRules = lodash.get(actionResult, 'response.alertRules', []);
    setAlertRules({ alertRules });    //Error form here
  };

  const groupedRules = lodash.groupBy(alertRules, 'resourceType');
  const levelTypes = lodash.uniq(alertRules.map((alert: Alert) => alert.level));
  return (
    <FieldArray
      name="alertRules"
      component={CoordinateSelect}
      label={t('å‘Šè­¦è§„åˆ™')}
      firstOptions={lodash.keys(groupedRules)}
      secondOptions={groupedRules}
      thirdOptions={levelTypes}
      required
    />
  );
};
export default connector(AlertRuleForm);
```

the error is when set state

> Argument of type '{ alertRules: any; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction'.
>     Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'alertRules' does not exist in type 'SetStateAction'.ts(2345)

Comment: I wonder why you use curly braces `setAlertRules({ alertRules });` I think it should be  `setAlertRules(alertRules);` as you now provide object with field alertRules and not an array

Comment: Yes, as pointed by @maciej Trojiniarz you need to remove the curly braces

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Short Answer** :- Remove the curly braces from the setAlertRules statement , as it is leading to an inconsistency between the `type` of `setAlertRules` at the definition and its usage.

This is feature of ES6 known as ***Object literal Shorthand***.

At the time of Defining the *alertRules* the type of *setAlertRules* is *SetStateAction< Alert [ ] >* . And you are trying to give it value of type *{alertRules: any}* , which is leading to the error .

The value passed to `alertRules` is an object with key `alertRules` and its value as the array of type `Alert`.

So ,remove the curly brace as it is converted to something this

```
 setAlertRules({ alertRules: alertRules  }); 
  // now {alertRules: any} this thing will make sense
```

try this code for updation of alertRules .

```
// see no curly braces .
 setAlertRules( alertRules );
```